# Opacity only holds for a second

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

I want to set opacity to 40% on the backgroundView in a UIViewcontroller

I have set the opacity in Storyboard:

[image: I have set the opacity in Storyboard:]

It holds the correct opacity for about 1 second, and then the background turns completely black.

I have not set the background color anywhere in `viewDidLoad` or anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to set `self.view.isOpaque = false` and `self.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext`.

In storyboard for your `controller` see below screen captures:

[image]

For your `view` see below screen captures:

[image]